# Font size consistency

Tags: google-chrome

Most websites use the browser's default font size, which by default is 16px. However, there has been an unfortunate trend in recent years for some websites (e.g. medium.com) to use very large font sizes. For those websites, I just change the zoom setting in the browser to view the fonts at a smaller size, to bring them the same as normal websites. Typically, I use around 75% zoom.

However, I don't want to keep having to do that every time I visit a new website.

Is there a way to tell Chrome that if all the fonts on a certain page are big, that it should reduce the zoom automatically to bring the font sizes back to the default of 16px?